# I have a list of tuples and want to make a list that has only one instance of one of the strings in the tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I have this list of tuples :

```
[(1, 'Twilight Sparkle', 2, 'Fluttershy'), (1, 'Twilight Sparkle', 3,
'Applejack'), (1, 'Twilight Sparkle', 4, 'Pinkie Pie'), (1, 'Twilight
Sparkle', 5, 'Rarity'), (1, 'Twilight Sparkle', 6, 'Rainbow Dash'),
(1, 'Twilight Sparkle', 7, 'Princess Celestia'), (1, 'Twilight
Sparkle', 8, 'Princess Luna'), (2, 'Fluttershy', 3, 'Applejack'), (2,
'Fluttershy', 4, 'Pinkie Pie'), (2, 'Fluttershy', 5, 'Rarity'), (2,
'Fluttershy', 6, 'Rainbow Dash'), (2, 'Fluttershy', 7, 'Princess
Celestia'), (2, 'Fluttershy', 8, 'Princess Luna'), (3, 'Applejack', 4,
'Pinkie Pie'), (3, 'Applejack', 5, 'Rarity'), (3, 'Applejack', 6,
'Rainbow Dash'), (3, 'Applejack', 7, 'Princess Celestia'), (3,
'Applejack', 8, 'Princess Luna'), (4, 'Pinkie Pie', 5, 'Rarity'), (4,
'Pinkie Pie', 6, 'Rainbow Dash'), (4, 'Pinkie Pie', 7, 'Princess
Celestia'), (4, 'Pinkie Pie', 8, 'Princess Luna'), (5, 'Rarity', 6,
'Rainbow Dash'), (5, 'Rarity', 7, 'Princess Celestia'), (5, 'Rarity',
8, 'Princess Luna'), (6, 'Rainbow Dash', 7, 'Princess Celestia'), (6,
'Rainbow Dash', 8, 'Princess Luna'), (7, 'Princess Celestia', 8,
'Princess Luna')]
```

And i want to create a list from it that only has the first time a string appear, in this instance i want the list to be:

```
[(1, 'Twilight Sparkle', 2, 'Fluttershy'), (3, 'Applejack', 4, 'Pinkie
Pie'),(5, 'Rarity', 6, 'Rainbow Dash'), (7, 'Princess Celestia', 8,
'Princess Luna')]
```

Comment: Note that your example output is more restrictive than the description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could keep a `set` of elements that have already been used.

Add a tuple to the result only if none of the elements have been used before:

```
data = [(1, 'Twilight Sparkle', 2, 'Fluttershy'), (1, 'Twilight Sparkle', 3, 'Applejack'), (1, 'Twilight Sparkle', 4, 'Pinkie Pie'), (1, 'Twilight Sparkle', 5, 'Rarity'), (1, 'Twilight Sparkle', 6, 'Rainbow Dash'), (1, 'Twilight Sparkle', 7, 'Princess Celestia'), (1, 'Twilight Sparkle', 8, 'Princess Luna'), (2, 'Fluttershy', 3, 'Applejack'), (2, 'Fluttershy', 4, 'Pinkie Pie'), (2, 'Fluttershy', 5, 'Rarity'), (2, 'Fluttershy', 6, 'Rainbow Dash'), (2, 'Fluttershy', 7, 'Princess Celestia'), (2, 'Fluttershy', 8, 'Princess Luna'), (3, 'Applejack', 4, 'Pinkie Pie'), (3, 'Applejack', 5, 'Rarity'), (3, 'Applejack', 6, 'Rainbow Dash'), (3, 'Applejack', 7, 'Princess Celestia'), (3, 'Applejack', 8, 'Princess Luna'), (4, 'Pinkie Pie', 5, 'Rarity'), (4, 'Pinkie Pie', 6, 'Rainbow Dash'), (4, 'Pinkie Pie', 7, 'Princess Celestia'), (4, 'Pinkie Pie', 8, 'Princess Luna'), (5, 'Rarity', 6, 'Rainbow Dash'), (5, 'Rarity', 7, 'Princess Celestia'), (5, 'Rarity', 8, 'Princess Luna'), (6, 'Rainbow Dash', 7, 'Princess Celestia'), (6, 'Rainbow Dash', 8, 'Princess Luna'), (7, 'Princess Celestia', 8, 'Princess Luna')]

already_added = set()
result = []

for quad in data:
    if not any((x in already_added) for x in quad):
        for x in quad:
            already_added.add(x)
        result.append(quad)

print(result)
# [(1, 'Twilight Sparkle', 2, 'Fluttershy'), (3, 'Applejack', 4, 'Pinkie Pie'), (5, 'Rarity', 6, 'Rainbow Dash'), (7, 'Princess Celestia', 8, 'Princess Luna')]
```

Note that this code corresponds to the desired output, not the description in your question. This desired output is more restrictive, and some elements won't be added at all if there are always coupled to already seen elements. For:

```
data = [(1, 'a', 2, 'b'), (1, 'a', 3, 'c'), (2, 'b', 4, 'd')]
```

the output will be:

```
[(1, 'a', 2, 'b')]
```

No `3`, `4`, `c` or `d` in sight!